# How to have airplane mode by default on in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, airplane-mode

I am electrosensitive and need my computer to be always with the airplane mode on and since I updated to ubuntu 20.04, bluetooth and wifi is on time to time.
Is there a way to force the airplane mode to be always on?
I am even fine de deactivate it totally as I won't use it.

Thank you

Comment: It is actually quite easy to completely but reversably disable your wireless, if that is what you are asking. You may blacklist the driver. Find it with the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Answer (score 3):

you can add a startup application preference like this with the command

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Rfkill --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill' 'AirplaneMode' '<true>'
```

[image]

To turn off Airplane mode in a session, run

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Rfkill --method org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill' 'AirplaneMode' '<false>'
```

To remove startup preference, Remove it from Startup Applications Preference.

Comment: Excellent, I will try this out immediately.  Thank you so much

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It keep turning on with wifi on. I need a solution that it works.

Comment: did you add the command to startup applications?

Comment: What if you run the command in a terminal when bluetooth or wifi on?

Comment: This does work for me (Ubuntu 22.04), however airplane mode is enabled from startup until I log in, so it does not prevent airplane mode from getting turned off at startup.

Comment: Yes since some fewer versions of Ubuntu `gdbus call --session ...` command does not work due to security reasons. for this to work one must create gnome-shell-extension and use it.

Answer (score 1):

First, list the available devices:

`rfkill list`

Your bluetooth adapter may be numbered `1` and called `hci0`. Now disable it:

`rfkill block 1`

and so on for the other devices.
This will persist across boots.

Comment: I did try with rfkill already but didn't persist after reboot...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: I experience the same as michael (Ubuntu 22.04) - this does not persist when I turn off and on my laptop.