# How can I prevent airplane mode from getting turned off on restart?

Tags: wireless, startup, 22.04, airplane-mode

For some reason, airplane mode gets turned off on restart. This is a *ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen6*, running Ubuntu 22.04 (GNOME), but earlier Ubuntu versions were the same.

Ideally, I would like Ubuntu to just respect my last setting. I'm on wired Ethernet almost all the time, so why expose myself to microwave radiation and consume power for a feature I don't need?

If it is not possible to make Ubuntu just keep airplane mode like the user set it, is it possible to set a default for startup (and whatever other occasions Ubuntu may deem it okay to switch airplane mode off)?

If possible, I still want to be able to turn airplane mode on as usual without having to edit with special settings, in those rare cases where I do want to use it.

What I've tried so far:

- `rfkill block 1` as described in https://askubuntu.com/a/1245890/529763, but despite the writer's claim to persist across boots, it does not.
- turning on airplane mode at startup a la https://askubuntu.com/a/1245972/529763, which does work, however airplane mode is still turned off after restart until the time I log in; what I would like instead is for airplane mode to stay off

Comment: Use "edit" to add information on your Ubuntu version and the desktop environment you use to your question. A solution can depend on that.

Comment: In standard Ubuntu with GNOME once you turn off WiFi and/or Bluetooth they stay off after rebooting.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Not for me apparently - not sure if there is some setting for this, or if it even depends on the hardware.

Comment: Indeed it may depend on the hardware and maybe I'm lucky in that regard because any laptop, miniPC or desktop I've used recently behaved as described above with internal or USB devices and often a mix of PCIe WiFi and USB Bluetooth.

Comment: I suggest checking UEFI settings. It's conceivable to have some setting regarding "initial state" for the radios although I never came across such thing. And, of course, updating UEFI is always my recommendation before further troubleshooting.

Comment: @ChanganAuto By "UEFI settings", do you mean the BIOS? I've checked every option there, without success.

Comment: I actually meant UEFI :) BIOS has been replaced a long time ago. They're both firmwares  with roughly the same purpose (UEFI has a lot more functionality though). Unfortunately 10 years after Microsoft sort of forced vendors to preinstall Windows in UEFI mode, therefore many more years since the first UEFI implementation, many manufacturers and experts still use the old acronym (or UEFI BIOS) for something that isn't and hasn't been for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

Then turn airplane mode on and reboot.

Then enable the Network Manager service again so you can use LAN:

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
```

For me, from now on, airplane mode stays on after reboot and LAN works fine.